# Strange render anomaly during window resize

Tags: debian, graphics, desktop-environment, intel-graphics, opengl

When I resize the window in any environment, sometimes I see a strange anomaly, which lasts until more resize or mouse drop.

It's same in each environment and with all windows.

**Here it is:**

[image: Anomaly]
It's strange, isn't it?

System: **Debian 9 Stretch**

Graphic card: **Intel HD graphic 530**

```
:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center                                                                                                                    
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)                                                                                                      
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.6                                                                                                                  
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50                                                                                                                           
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Is there any known problem, which I should study or settings, which can repair this problem? Do you have any experience? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the palinopsia bug, a old, embarrassing security and privacy leak in graphics drivers: that no one fixes: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123756/how-to-mitigate-risk-of-x11-buffer-ghosting-palinopsia-bug

Comment: @mviereck Thank you for this thread. I think Intel HD 530 is nowadays frequently used card, so why video drivers still aren't optimized?

Comment: Drivers should zero the video RAM when it is allocated; it often shows content from previous applications. It is not done because it costs a minimal bit of performance. To optimize performance, security and privacy are dropped. This affects Intel, AMD and Nvidia as well, open and closed source drivers as well,  Linux and Windows as well. At least, open source on linux could do better.

Comment: @mviereck Ok, thank you for explanation. But why do I have this problem "just me"? Is there something I do differently than others?

Comment: Mostly I see such artefacts only for milliseconds, not long enough for a screenshot as you describe in your question. I can't tell you more what may be different on your system.